# Cocos2D - remove layer opacity on region

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, opacity, layer, region, cut

I got a Scene with a layer with the top z-index wich one adds a dark effect to the whole scene setting its opacity. What i am trying to do now is to remove the shadow/dark effect in a concrete region (inside a cone/triangle) as the image shows (inside the red polygon). In other words, i want to have the same "luminosity" (zero opacity) inside the triangle as on the left side of the screen.

[image]

code:

```
-(id) init
{
if( (self=[super initWithColor:ccc4(0,0,0,128)] )) {
    CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

    CCLayerColor* layer1 = [CCLayerColor layerWithColor: ccc4(0, 0, 0, 180) width: winSize.width height: winSize.height];
    layer1.position = ccp(50,0);
    [self addChild: layer1 z:2];

    CCSprite *background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"background.png"];
    background.position = ccp(background.contentSize.width/2, background.contentSize.height/2);
    [self addChild:background];

    CCSprite *player = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Player.png"rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 27, 40)];
    player.position = ccp(player.contentSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
    [self addChild:player];     
}
return self;
}
```

any idea on how to do this ?? maybe i should try to do it on another whay and not use a CCLayer to add the dark effect ??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to use a CCSprite with a black image the size of the background. Then cut out the whole you need in an image program and draw that sprite over the background with lowered opacity.

Comment: the idea is to simulate a lamp's light, so the cutting-triangle would be created with code and coord to place the effect on the scene, so as i understand your idea is to create a sprite with the cutted area static. Maybe with some kind of render this could be possible ??